# Is there a pure functional equivalent to goog.object.extend?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, google-closure-library

Per [Closure documentation](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/namespace_goog_object.html):

> Extends an object with another object. This operates 'in-place'; it does not create a new Object. Example: var o = {}; goog.object.extend(o, {a: 0, b: 1}); o; // {a: 0, b: 1} goog.object.extend(o, {b: 2, c: 3}); o; // {a: 0, b: 2, c: 3}

But this is not a functional approach and for many contexts a functional approach is better. Does Closure offer something more modern for this?

e.g.

```
goog.object.extend(a, b);
```

becomes

```
a = goog.object.extend(a, b);
```

Comment: what would the code you'd like to write look like?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new object by using an empty object literal to be extended with the objects that you want to copy-merge:

```
var x = {};
goog.object.extend(x, a, b);
a = x;
```

If you are extending non-plain objects, you might need to use `Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(a))`.

Comment: This appears to be incorrect: `goog.object.extend()` doesn't return the first argument (as `jQuery.extend` does.

Comment: @Peeja: Hm, odd, did this change? I must have assumed it just would work.

Comment: I'm not sure, I've only just tried it. I assumed it would work too.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it yourself:

```js
var a = {};
var b = extend(a, { a: 0, b: 1 });
var c = extend(b, { b: 2, c: 3 });

console.log(a, b, c);

function extend(a, b) {
    var result = {};
    for (var x in a) if (a.hasOwnProperty(x)) result[x] = a[x];
    for (var x in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(x)) result[x] = b[x];
    return result;
}
```

Hope that helps.