# Is there a purely functional way to merge objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Say I have an object with some properties:

```
const obj = {
  key1: 1
  key2: 2
}
```

and I have a function `someFunc` that takes one object as a parameter. I want to pass `obj` with some additional parameters, like

```
someFunc({
  key1: 1
  key2: 2
  otherKey: 3
})
```

The problem is that I don't want to actually change the state of `obj`. After `someFunc` has been called it should not contain `otherKey` as a property.

This leaves `Object.assign` out of the question:

```
let ident = someObj => someObj;

ident(Object.assign(obj, {otherKey: 3}))
console.log(someObj); // -> {key1: 1, key2: 2, otherKey: 3}
```

Creating a new variable and assigning `otherKey = 3` to it does the same thing.

I know I can use some sort of deep duplication - but that seems like an unnecessarily complex way of handling a fairly simple problem.

The most elegant way of doing this would be a pure function that takes some objects `obj1, obj2`, returns the same output as `Object.assign(obj1, obj2)`, but alters neither of them. Is there some obvious way of doing this in JS that I haven't seen, or do I have to use some other library?

Comment: `someFunc( Object.assign({}, obj, {otherKey: 3}) );`

Comment: JS objects cannot be dynamically filled without mutation.

Comment: @Bergi is there some underlying reason to that?

Comment: @JohnHartman Maybe because OOP in JS is entirely imperative? It just wasn't designed with immutable objects as a primitive.

Comment: related: [Is there a pure functional equivalent to goog.object.extend?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29501474/1048572)

Answer (score 6):

Just reverse the parameters to `Object.assign` - it will add the properties from `obj` to a new object:

```
ident(Object.assign({otherKey: 3}, obj))
```

**Caution**

But you must be careful about properties that are already present in `obj` as they will overwrite the ones in the new array.

Comment: This is more often done like `ident(Object.assign({}, obj, { otherKey: 3 }))` so you know the object sent will always have `otherKey` value of `3` regardless of whether `obj` had an `otherKey` value already.

Answer (score 3):

You are dealing with *immutability*. Another way to accomplish thit is to use *spread* operator of ES6:

```js
const obj1 = {
  key1: 1,
  key2: 2,
}

const obj2 = {
  key1: 1,
  key2: 12,
  otherKey: 3
};

const merged = { ...obj1, ...obj2 };

console.log('merged: ', merged);
console.log('obj1: ', obj1);
console.log('obj2: ', obj2);
```

**You'll see that neither obj1 nor obj2 is altered**